# Parsing JSON node with arbitrary names

Tags: java, json, gson, retrofit2, android

I'm currently trying to parse a JSON like this

```
{
  "images": {
    "svg": {
      "arbitrary_name_1": {
        "src": "https://www.google.com"
      },
      "arbitrary_name_2": {
        "src": "https://www.google.com"
      }
    },
    "png": {
      "arbitrary_name_3": {
        "src": "https://www.google.com"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see there are a some arbitrary node names in there. What I'm trying to get is a `Map<String, String>` for node *svg* and *png* where the key is the arbitrary name and the value should be the `src` String. So my Images Bean should look like this:

```
public class Images {

    @SerializedName("svg")
    public Map<String, String> svg;
    @SerializedName("png")
    public Map<String, String> png;

}
```

Out of the box this doesn't work that's why I'm using a custom `JsonDeserializer`. After hours of trial and error I couldn't find a solution but all the ones I've implemented weren't working. Following just one:

```
@Override
public Map<String, String> deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> element : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject1 = element.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonElementEntry1 : jsonObject1.entrySet()) {
            JsonObject jsonObject2 = jsonElementEntry1.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
            for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonElementEntry2 : jsonObject2.entrySet()) {
                map.put(jsonElementEntry1.getKey(), jsonElementEntry2.getValue().getAsString());
            }
        }
    }
    return map;
}
```

This looks wrong, is wrong and on top of that is pretty inefficient. I'd be glad if someone could help me out and tell me what I'm missing and what would be the recommended/correct way. Thanks!

Comment: `svg` and `png` aren't arrays so you can't map them as `Map<String, String>`.

Comment: So you're saying that I need to create a SVG and PNG Pojo. What fields should I put in there? (I've tried this before as well and weren't successful either)

Comment: Yes, can't you change your JSON format? Where are you getting it from?

Comment: @chsdk I'd love to change the JSON structure unfortunately this isn't an option. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like I figured out a solution - finally... (though I had to add a new class like mentioned by [chsdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44117718/parsing-json-node-with-arbitrary-names#comment75263311_44117718))

#### Deserializer

```
@Override
public ImagePojo deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();

    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> element : json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet()) {
        JsonObject jsonObject1 = element.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
        for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> jsonElementEntry1 : jsonObject1.entrySet()) {
            String src = jsonElementEntry1.getValue().getAsString();
            map.put(element.getKey(), src);
        }
    }
    return new ImagePojo(map);
}
```

#### Images.class

```
public class Images {

    @SerializedName("svg")
    public ImagePojo svg;
    @SerializedName("png")
    public ImagePojo png;

}
```

#### ImagePojo.class

```
public class ImagePojo {

    public Map<String, String> map;

    public ImagePojo(Map<String, String> map) {
        this.map = map;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you should process JSON as map.

For class

```
public class Images {
    private Map<String, String> svg;
    private Map<String, String> png;

    public Map<String, String> getSvg() {
        return svg;
    }

    public void setSvg(Map<String, String> svg) {
        this.svg = svg;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getPng() {
        return png;
    }

    public void setPng(Map<String, String> png) {
        this.png = png;
    }
}
```

Use something like this:

```
public void parseImages() throws ParseException {
    String json = ...........;

    JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
    JSONObject jsonObject = (JSONObject) parser.parse(json);

    Images images = new Images();
    images.setSvg(getNames(jsonObject, "svg"));
    images.setPng(getNames(jsonObject, "png"));

}

private Map<String, String> getNames(JSONObject jsonObject, String itemName) {
    Map<String, String> rezMap = new HashMap<>();

    Map<String, Object> item =
            (Map<String, Object>)
                    ((Map<String, Object>)jsonObject.get("images")).get(itemName);

    for(Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : item.entrySet()) {
        rezMap.put(entry.getKey(), 
                (String)((Map<String, Object>)entry.getValue()).get("src"));
    }

    return rezMap;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately there is no way for me to do it this way since I don't parse the JSON manually (Retrofit calls the GSON parser on it's own).